# Object Defined Error 1004 and Formula won't come out

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Got a code from a member here (thanks a lot), but got an error with Pop-out error code 1004 on

```
With wsTarget
        .Range("A6").FormulaR1C1 = strFormulaCOA
        .Range("D6").FormulaR1C1 = strFormulaStatus
    End With
```

Any idea to fix the problem?

I try to give "" between the `strFormulaCOA` resulting the code to just insert `strFormulaCOA` word on the destinated range. Another thing, I also try to change the `FormulaR1C1` to value and formula but still no good.

here's the code I use

```
    Option Explicit
Sub insertCOAandStatusFormulas()

'Pattern of each formula part - $1 as placeholder for sheetname

Dim strPartCOA As String, strPartStatus As String
strPartCOA = "IFERROR(INDEX('$1'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'$1'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),INDEX('$1'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'$1'!R6C5:R2000C5,0)) "
strPartStatus = "IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'$1'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),VLOOKUP(RC3,'$1'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0) "


Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget2 As Worksheet
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rekap Capex")    '--> adjust this to your needs
Set wsTarget2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Depreciation")

'build sheet-specific part per formula
Dim strFormulaCOA As String, strFormulaStatus As String
Dim cntSheets As Long, i As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not ws.Name = wsTarget.Name And Not ws.Name = "Depreciation" Then
        strPartCOA = strFormulaCOA & Replace(strPartCOA, "$1", ws.Name) & vbCrLf
        strPartStatus = strFormulaStatus & Replace(strPartStatus, "$1", ws.Name) & vbCrLf
        cntSheets = cntSheets + 1
    End If
Next

'add equal-sign, remove last comma and add closing brackets
strFormulaCOA = "=" & strPartCOA & String(cntSheets, ")")
strFormulaStatus = "=" & strPartStatus & String(cntSheets, ")")

With wsTarget
    .Range("A6").FormulaR1C1 = strFormulaCOA
    .Range("D6").FormulaR1C1 = strFormulaStatus
End With

End Sub
```

Edit:

Below is the target of the formula (the blank cells) in which I want to add index match and vlookup formula

[image: the place of the formula]

the problem is that the sheet of the data is not always the same, as we know that vlookup and index match formula need to state the sheet name(the first and second sheet always the same).

[image: the number of the sheet not always the same]

this is what my vlookup formula looks like

[image: the vlookup formula]

this is what my index match formula looks like

[image: index match formula]

Comment: What I would do is put the formula in the cell, have a line of code to read the formula to a string and compare this with what you have.. Most likely a quote/double quote issue.

Comment: @Aldert sorry I totally beginner at VBA, could you give an example in which part should I change?

Comment: Bad idea to past the formula as image. No one can use this anymore and no one is going to retype with the risk for error. If you want this to be of added value, past the formula as code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I highly recommended to use formulas A1 instead R1C1 because it's easyly to understand. To insert in this formula a listname follow the example:

```
fformula = "=FormulaExample(" & Chr(39) & lst1 & Chr(39) & "!$B$3:$B$" & (n + 3) & "," & Chr(39) & lst1 & Chr(39) & "!L3:L" & (n + 3) & ",$C$2,$D$2,$E$2,$F$2,$B$7," & Chr(39) & lst1 & Chr(39) & "!$AA$3:$AA$" & (n + 3) & ")"
```

where  lst1 = "listexample"

`chr(int) returns an ASCII symbol`

`chr(39) returns dot`
Remember that formula inserts with "," instead of ";" (A1,B1 not A1;B1)

That code will be like this:

```
=FormulaExample('listexample'!$B$3:$B$88000;'listexample'!L3:L88000;$C$2;$D$2;$E$2;$F$2;$B$7;'listexample'!$AA$3:$AA$88000;J2)
```

And to insert:

```
with wsTarget:
    .Range("A1").Formula = fformula
```

Please edit your code with A1 code style or give me a picture of sheet/file and I will help you to code

Comment: I just add some picture of my sheet and problems. For the formula, sorry that I can't understand what is A1 code style and how to do it since I'm totally new at VBA. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, to see how formula is looking try macrorecorder (howto see [link](https://trumpexcel.com/record-macro-vba/)). Tools->Options->General and unchecking the R1C1 Reference Style to change R1C1 to A1

Comment: I don't find the R1C1 Reference Style to change R1C1 to A1. I only find Form Grid Settings, Show ToolTips, Edit and Continue, Error Trapping, and Compile

Comment: Ok, my friend, just show me your two formulas that you wanted to insert (how it looks in excel sheet)

Comment: I just add some pictures of the formula on the post

Comment: the formula I use depends on the sheet so if one of the sheets is absent, then excel would ask to update the unavailable sheet value. On the code, I try to make the vlookup and index match function to just run on the available sheet only